# matrix multiplication index notation

Tags: calculus, matrices

I am trying to write a product of matrices in index notation.

Recall the product of two matrices $X,Y$ is just

$$
(XY)_{a i} = X_{ab}Y_{bi}
$$
where repeated indices are summed over, in this case, $b$. My question is for the following matrix multiplication: 
$$
X^\top \bar{X} X^\top +X^\top X X^H 
$$
where $\bar{X}$ is the complex conjugate of the matrix $X$; $X^\top, X^H$ are the real transpose and hermitian transpose respectively.  How can I write this in index notation?

My solution is below, if you could tell me if it is wrong or not.  Thanks!
$$
(X^\top \bar{X} X^\top +X^\top X X^H)_{ai}
$$
The first term is:
$$
(X^\top \bar{X} X^\top)_{ai}= X^\top_{ak}  \bar{X}_{kb}  X^\top_{b i}= X_{ka}\bar{X}_{kb}X_{ib}
$$
and the second term I get :
$$
(X^\top X X^H)_{ai}= X^\top_{ak} X_{kb} X^H_{bi}= X_{ka}X_{kb} \bar{X}_{ib}
$$
since $X^H= \bar{X}^\top$.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Just for clarification, in your solution you also sum them over the same indices right?

Comment: As I stated, 'repeated indices are summed over'.  Is this what you mean?  I can write the sums out explicitly if that will help, thanks a lot! In my solution, I sum over $k,b$ for both terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your notation

\begin{align}
(X^T\bar{X}X^T)_{ai}&=(X^T)_{ak}(\bar{X}X^T)_{ki} \\ 
&=X_{ka}\bar{X}_{kb}X^T_{bi} \\
&=X_{ka}\bar{X}_{kb}X_{ib}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
(X^TXX^H)_{ai}&=(X^T)_{ak}(XX^H)_{ki} \\ 
&=X_{ka}X_{kb}X^H_{bi} \\
&=X_{ka}X_{kb}\bar{X}_{ib}
\end{align}

Summing them up

$$X_{ka}\bar{X}_{kb}X_{ib}+X_{ka}X_{kb}\bar{X}_{ib}=2X_{ka}\Re(\bar{X}_{kb}X_{ib})$$

Here, $\Re$ refers to the real part of a complex number.